# Javascript fetch api with unlimited timeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, timeout, fetch

I have a web worker with a fetch request that returns an error after some time.
I am not sure if it is because of timeout, but i want it to have un unlimited timeout. 
This is my code inside webWorker:

```
 fetch(data.defaults + 'returnSqlRes.php',
    {
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(data.sql)
    })
    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(function (sData) {

        var dt={};
        dt['o']=data.tableId;
        dt['data']=sData;
        _.forEach(dt.data[0],function (row) {
            row.DT_RowId = composeId(data.pk, row);
            _.forEach( data.tableCols,function (o, index) {
                if (_.has(o, 'complexList')) {
                    var fieldName = o.attr.desigColumn ? o.attr.desigColumn : o.attr.name;
                    var field = o.name;
                    var keys = returnListKeys(o);
                    var search = '';
                 _.forEach(  keys, function (name, i) {
                        if (i < keys.length - 1) {
                            search += row[name] + '@';
                        } else {
                            search += row[name];
                        }
                    });
                    var result = _.find(data.loadedData[getComplexListIndex(o)], {VAL: search});
                    if (result == undefined) {
                        row[field] = "";
                    } else {
                        row[field] = result[fieldName];
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        self.postMessage(downloadCSV(dt));
```

The final purpose of code is to download a csv file. The problem is sometimes i have 150k or 200k records and it takes time to parse and a network error is downloaded instead of the file. In tables with less than 100k records everything is ok, file is downloaded.

Comment: show the error. I guess it is server timeout exception.

Comment: failed to load response data...

Comment: no data or error is returned from server....

Answer (score 0):

Came Across this might help https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175 good luck!

Comment: the problem is sometimes the response is ex: 19 mb , even 80 mb and thats when i get no response from the server. I only get the 200ok and the response size , but no response content...Strange